# How do I use comparison symbols with input in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that will respond to someones age but I can't figure out how to use the comparison symbols. Here is the code I'm trying to run,

```
age = input('How old are you? \n >>')
if (age < 20):
    print('Hey you are pretty young.')
if (age > 20):
    print('wow you are pretty old')
```

But when I try to run this I get this Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Computer science/week 6/age.py", line 2, in <module>
    if (age < 20):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `age` is a `str`, you cannot compare `str` objects with `int` objects...

Comment: Is the error message not clear enough?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: I have already accepted an answer. And it's not really the same @B. Go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get as input is a string, you need to cast it to an int before you can compare it:

```
age = int(input('How old are you? \n >>'))
```

Better yet, add some error handling, e.g.:

```
try:
    age = int(input('How old are you? \n >>'))

except ValueError as ex:
    print("Not a valid age.")
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! I needed that.

Comment: @jamylak age = float(input("Enter any number: "))

Comment: @B.Go: I am pretty sure that with nearly 100k jamylak was just making a joke here.